# Laravel 4: try...catch not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, try-catch

I have a code that is something like this:

```
class ClassName extends BaseController implements InterfaceCrudController {
    public function FunctionName() {
        $error = null;
        $messenge = null;
        $request = Request::all();

        try {
            $query = DB::table("TableName")->where("Field_1", "=", $request["Field_1"])->where("Field_2", "=", $request["Field_2"]);

            $query->update(array(
                "Data_1" => $request["Data_1"],
                "Data_2" => $request["Data_2"]
            ));

            $error = false;
            $messenge = "Success";
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $error = true;
            $messenge = "Error: " . $e;
        }

        return Response::json(array(
            "error"  => $error,
            "messenge" => $messenge
        ));
    }
}
```

The problem I am having here is: when you run the **update()**, the execution stops and goes to an error screen saying "*Whoops, looks like something went wrong.*"
I've tried several things, but I can not find a way to make the script show me the **exception**.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us some actual code and the error's stack trace? Theres nothing wrong with your example code, but w/e is throwing the error isn't in your try catch statement.

Comment: I wrote the code as faithful as possible. In fact, only what changes are the variables.
The stack trace, it looks like this:

**1. Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
…/­app/­controllers/­GruposUsuariosController.php70
0. Illuminate\Exception\Handler handleShutdown
<#unknown>0**

"GruposUsuariosController.php70" is the line where it is given the update.

Comment: Nah, try catch should work just fine with the code you've posted. Check your code again, you probably have a namespace wrong or something.

Comment: I assume you're setting up the $request array somewhere ... ?

Comment: @J.T.Grimes Sorry, I forgot that variable. Post edited.

Answer (score 0):

The "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." page is the default view laravel will display if there is an error. To get more information about the error, including the stack trace, turn debug mode on in app/config/app.php by the doing this:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Debug Mode
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
| stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
| application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
|
*/

'debug' => false,
```

Comment: The problem is not that. The problem is that the Exception is not returning anything to me.